# Amazon EC2 creates automatically if I use S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Amazon EC2 creates automatically if I use S3?

I use only S3.

Comment: what does it create automatically?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To improve the chance of obtaining a useful answer, please Edit your question to provide additional information. For example, please explain what you are trying to accomplish, what you have tried so far, and what difficulties/errors you have experienced. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, if you use S3 it won't automatically create an Amazon EC2 Instance if that is what you are referring to. Can you clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

An AWS EC2 instance/server is different from S3. 
If you use AWS S3 to upload/download store files no EC2 servers will be launched. 
You can access these files through AWS console or through AWS Cli on your local machine.